# In a Swift application why WatchKit and NSNotificationCenter is working one way only?

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, watchkit

When a NSNotificationCenter notification send from WatchKit Extension InterfaceController we can get it from ViewController but when notification send from ViewController we can not get it from WatchKit Extension InterfaceController.

Here is the working notification;

We set notification in ViewController as

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:    "action_notification_WatchButton:", name: "notification_WatchButton", object: nil) 

 }
```

We get notification from in ViewController with

```
 func action_notification_WatchButton(notification:NSNotification) {

    println("watch button touched")        
}
```

We send notification from WatchKit Extension InterfaceController as

```
     @IBAction func buttonWatch() {

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("notification_WatchButton", object:nil, userInfo:nil)

}
```

So that works while both watch and phone applications are running. When we touch button watch

println("watch button touched")

prints the text. Very nice.

But when we set notification in

```
override func willActivate() {

  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:    "action_notification_WatchButton:", name: "notification_WatchButton", object: nil)  

 }
```

and we put

```
  func action_notification_WatchButton(notification:NSNotification) {

    println("phone button touched")        
}
```

under InterfaceController at WatchKit Extension and we use

```
@IBAction func buttonPhone() {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("notification_WatchButton", object:nil, userInfo:nil)
  }
```

inside of ViewController button function there is no answer as the button touched on Phone.

Answer (score 3):

You should read up on [Darwin notifications](http://www.mutualmobile.com/posts/mmwormhole) and [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole). That will solve your notification issues.

Comment: I see, there is no way of sending notification that way from ViewController to WatchKit Extension at the moment. But, it must be, I believe  Apple is going to make it possible after some time. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There absolutely is if they are both running. It is called Darwin Notifications. You send a Darwin notification from the ViewController, and register for it in the Watch Extension which will receive it almost immediately. MMWormhole is merely an example of how the send and receive can be done.

Comment: Hi @Hope, if this answer is sufficient could you upvote and mark as such?

Comment: actually it should be flagged for being a link only answer